# How to get NetLogo to run a function every 30 minutes

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get NetLogo to run a function every 30 minutes. Can anyone suggest how to do this? Thanks.

The structure of go looks like this:

```
to go
get-data (run every 30 mins)
execute-and-return-decision-based-on-the-data-just-retrieved
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`every`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#every). It makes sure the given command block runs *at most* once per time period. Anyway, if your go is being run by a forever button, then this should work:

```
to go
  every 30 * 60 [
    get-data
    execute-and-return-decision-based-on-the-data-just-retrieved
  ]
end
```